# Watir-webdriver vs Mechanize to avoid Amazon's evercookies\zombiecookies

Tags: ruby, security, cookies, mechanize, watir-webdriver

I'm working on a way to automatically upload \ manage stuff on the amazon kindle platform on multiple accounts.

I have been told by someone who has extensive experience with amazon that Amazon notoriously utilizes some sort of a [permanent cookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) (Which I guess was a basis for a couple of lawsuits). They can be stored in flash, as a generated .png which is then forced to be cached and any number of things; check out the link. I'm concerned about this.

Currently, all of the scripts I use to manage uploads are written in Ruby and use slightly buggy but nonetheless pretty neat watir-webdriver. As far as I understand it, each instance of the watir-webdriver driven Firefox is it's own unique instance with no cookies. But can Firefox still transmit data from these evercookies to amazon through flash storage or any number of clever ways? I'm really not sure.

My questions are:

a) What does watir-webdriver clear before starting a new "session" of a browser other than http cookies?

b) In theory, if I find out all the places amazon is leaving these cookies, can I manually clear them each time before I start the instance of a browser?

c) If I re-write the scripts using Mechanize rather than watir-webdriver, will that avoid ALL of these problems as mechanize (afaik) is completely unable to run javascript code?

Would you recommend using mechanize to avoid these cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think, but the answers are fairly obvious:

- Firefox will send permanent cookies but not session cookies from old sessions
- Yes it's theoretically possible to delete a browser's permanent cookies.
- Yes it will avoid those problems if you use mechanize

Personally I've scraped Amazon with mechanize many times. They would prefer you to use the API but sometimes there's something you just can't get that way.